# Can't refresh datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a `DataGrid`, which loads the data on start up. There are several buttons on which the user can click. Each button updates the same column. The problem is that when the new value of that column is saved, the old value is still shown in the data grid. It must be refreshed. I have tried several ways to do it, like: `t_KlantenDataGrid.Items.Refresh()` and `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(t_KlantenDataGrid.ItemsSource).Refresh()`. None of them works.

The code which loads the data:

```
OV.AOVDataSet aOVDataSet = ((AOV.AOVDataSet)(this.FindResource("aOVDataSet")));
// Load data into the table t_Klanten. You can modify this code as needed.
AOV.AOVDataSetTableAdapters.t_KlantenTableAdapter aOVDataSett_KlantenTableAdapter = new AOV.AOVDataSetTableAdapters.t_KlantenTableAdapter();
aOVDataSett_KlantenTableAdapter.Fill(aOVDataSet.t_Klanten);
t_KlantenViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("t_KlantenViewSource")));
t_KlantenViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

I use `Entity Framework`. Why doesn't those two solutions work for me. Are there any other solutions to refresh the `DataGrid`?

Comment: In the past I've had to re-load the dataset, and rebind the grid. Refreshing the dataset doesn't inform the grid to display new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers. As Jasmine suggested, I reloaded the dataset and rebounded the datagrid. Maybe it's not the best way to do it but it was the only solution I had then.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the old value with that type of data binding, it means you don't update the initial source, but only the temporary one (in your case t_KlantenViewSource). Calling Refresh method on the data added by `FindResource` cause app to reload it from pre-compiled resource, which won't change in this case.

In other words, the problem is you use pre-compiled resource

On the same time, you fill the dataset with actual data, but your dataset is in memory, view source - inside application file.

You can try:

- binding ItemsSource of the entire datagrid or separate column to the TableAdapter dataset
- change resource compiling behaviour to Content, thus the app will reload it from external file each time you call Refresh method.

ADDITION:

You can find a [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples) for your case, just to save time. Check paragraph "performing updates" Other way is to provide NotifyPropertyChanged Event for each bound parameter, but I can't say it is better in this case, assuming you update columns via unique buttons.

To be short, you need a method like this on your button clicked / property changed:
 `aOVDataSett_KlantenTableAdapter.Update(aOVDataSet.t_Klanten)`

Comment: Thank you very much for you solutions. I don't have so much experience with WPF and EF. I would really appreciate if you could provide an example of the given solutions.

Comment: OK, I got the second solution. But when I try that, I get so many errors. Like cannot initialize.

Comment: Then please show XAML of the DataGrid, need to see your column data bindings (if any)

Answer (score 0):

after button click first set datagrid datasource to null then assign the datas

```
  datagrid.datasource=null
```